# Setting up responsive content within a responsive theme

Tags: nodes, theming

I want to make a layout INSIDE the main content which is responsive.
I've read through dozens of pages, watched several videos and still there is no clear path to acomplish resposive content.
I started out with the latest Zen, but Display Suite and Panels let me place my fields in different grid layouts, but these grids end up not being responsive.

I now installed Omega, ending up having the same issue.
So, which theme and which modules let me setup a responsive grid WITHIN the main content?

Comment: are you tried Zen-grids, with compass, and sass?

Comment: I was hoping to get around Zen-Grids. I have no experience with compass and sass. Is it really the only option to learn all this just to be able to swith a side-by-side design into stacked within the content?

Comment: Compass and SASS are awesome.  In the end I think you will be happy you used them.

Comment: No, you don't need to learn SASS/COMPASS (but you might-should want to!) You can easily use Zen 5 Responsive Theme by editing the CSS files directly, not the SCSS files. Panels is not responsive unless you use Panels Extra Layouts.

Comment: Panels is not responsive. You will need to create your own layouts or use panelizer. Omega is responsive and you should not run into problems with it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Zen theme, best way(i hope so) to do responsive design is - [Zen grids](http://zengrids.com/),
First u need to install [ruby gems](http://docs.rubygems.org/read/chapter/3), after you installed u need two more things, as root install [sass](http://sass-lang.com/download.html) and [compass](http://compass-style.org/) and ofc. zen-grids

```
gem install sass 
gem install compass
gem install zen-grids
```

Then go to your theme folder, and write `compass watch` now all your css yo need to write in `sass` folder it will produce css in same files in your css folder. To do blocks responsive, in `Layouts` folder(ofc if you are using Zen sub theme) u will see `responsive-sidebars.scss`  or similar, now u need to import `@import "zen";// Import Zen Grids with this statement.` and write **zen-grids** code in your `responsive-sidebars.scss`. Read more about Zen grids - [*here*](http://zengrids.com/).
*I hope it helps.*

Comment: neok: thank you. I will consider working myself into this. Still i was hoping to get a Module based solution...

Comment: its really awesome solution tbh), this is not really hard, try it. and good luck finding that module, but i think there is no 100% solution for this, u will probably will need to write some css, without zen-grids and sass, damn hard work :D

Comment: alright, thanks for your input guys. I'll start right now...

Comment: if you do so, don't forget to install Bundler : it manages your appli's dependencies through its entire life, across many machines, systematically and repeatably. In command line "cd <path to your sub-theme's directory>" then "bundle install". Once done, check in your subtheme directory, bundler should have written a new file : gemfile.lock. This is your insurance ;)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need get into zen grids just for responsive layout. Use Zen 5 responsive layout, and then put your content in the main content area as usual, and you have a responsive and adaptive website. Well, read up on responsive images.

I haven't tried this with Display Suite, but I assume it lets you set responsive columns. I use Panelizer with Extra Layouts, which are responsive.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for the best way to use both Panels with a responsive design, you might be really interested in  [Adaptivetheme](https://drupal.org/project/adaptivetheme) : it has a great Panels support, it is used by almost 50.000 sites (!), has subthemes and an extensive [documentation](http://adaptivethemes.com/documentation).